# Flutter MultiSelectBottomSheet: how to fix crash on size change?

Tags: flutter

I use a MultiSelectBottomSheet from multi_select_flutter ( https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter )

It works all like expected, I can select/deselect chips and get it back to my code. But if I swipe the sheet down it crashes with a "_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)" on "_selectedItems = myVar!;" (line 439) in pub.dev\multi_select_flutter-4.1.3\lib\bottom_sheet\multi_select_bottom_sheet_field.dart

I wouldn't need the size change of the sheet but couldn't find an option to disable this. Any hint on how to fix the original problem would be great too.

The problem happens no matter if I select some chips or not. That's my call:

```
    return MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
      initialChildSize: 0.5,
      listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
      // searchable: true,
      buttonText: const Text("choose suitable tags"),
      title: const Text("Tags"),
      items: items,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please select at least one tag!';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onConfirm: (value) {
        // do stuff
      },
      chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
```